# How to use Mockk to mock a dependency in tested class without passing it in as an argument?

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockk

If I want to test a method that uses some 3rd party library, and I want to mock that library, the documentation seems to suggest that I need to pass in a mocked instance of a library class.

But what if the class imports its own dependencies, like this?

```
class SomeClass {
    import SomeLibrary

    fun MethodIWantToTest(val input) {
        val newinput = DoSomething(input)
        val instance = SomeLibrary()
        val result = instance.processData(newinput)
        return result
    }
}

class SomeTest {
    @Test
    fun TestSomething(){
        val sc = SomeClass
        AssertEquals (true, sc.MethodIWantToTest(false))
    }
}
```

Can I still mock `SomeLibrary`, and how would I do that?

Comment: Is SomeLibrary.processData a static method call?

Comment: Code edited to make it an instance method call, but I would also like to mock static methods

Comment: The code is not valid, are you new to Kotlin?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I believe that this design is bad and not testable. Class initializing its dependencies makes the testing hard, where you introduce reflection and other stuff to have reasonable coverage. If that class initializes the dependency itself, then it is a private thing, so it should not be mocked, just like the reason why private methods are not tested.

Comment: Understood, thanks